# file hyperlink not working under tmux

Tags: tmux, hyperlink, ls

When using `tmux` hyperlink feature does not work.

For example:

```
ls --hyperlink *.pdf
```

list `.pdf` files and provide a link to click and open when using under terminal emulator, but fails when using `tmux`. I've tried `gnome-terminal` and `kitty`. Same result in both of them.

[image: screenshot of the result with and without tmux]

The screenshots above show the results on `kitty` without `tmux` on the left and with `tmux` on the right. When the mouse cursor is over, only on the left we have a visible and clickable link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Show the output on e.g. a screenshot. Also, what's your tmux version (`tmux -V`)?

Comment: tmux version 3.3a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because your version of tmux literally does not support hyperlinks.

Hyperlink marking is something that must be handled by *each* terminal emulation layer – it cannot be simply passed through, as it would cause a mess as soon as you had two vertical panes side-by-side, with a hyperlink that's supposed to be confined in one pane expanding across both. The multiplexer (tmux) needs to keep track of hyperlinks the same way it keeps track of text colors and other attributes.

Support for hyperlinks has been added to tmux in Git a few months ago and will be available in the next release, probably 3.4. (It seems it will also need a very modern ncurses version.)

Comment: I've just found the feature request here: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/911 which was opened and closed in 2017. Many version came since then but I found no mention of it probably coming in version 3.4. Are you certain it was not incorporated yet?

Comment: I looked at the actual source code history in Git, and I saw the actual commits adding this feature, all of them being *after* the `3.3_a` release had been tagged.

Comment: I just installed tmux from source (Latest commit 2023-06-08 f41c536f) and ran: python -c "import rich; rich.print('[link=/home]/home[/link]')" to test if links would work, but it didn't seem to. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Maybe my ncurses is too old?